# How to display individual values from an array in different objects?

Tags: javascript

As my first JavaScript project I decided to build a color pallete generator, which picks 3 random elements from 'cores[]' in hexadecimal values then pushing these 3 to another array 'listaHex[]'. Everything goes fine until I try to use 'text.content' in 3 divs to display each value from 'listaHex[]'. For some reason it works only for listaHex[0] as the other values dont appear at all.

```js
var botaogerar = document.getElementById("botao-gerar");

var cores = ['#CF2F2F', '#CF2FB2', '#732FCF', '#2F40CF', '#2FCFCA', '#36CF2F', '#CFC02F', '#F97D00', '#6F4535', '#787878', '#202020', '#009BDF'];

botaogerar.addEventListener("click", function(){
    
    for (i = 0; i < 3 ; i++){
        var listaHex = [];
        var codhex = "";
        var indiceArray = escolheCorNoArray();
        codhex += cores[indiceArray];
        listaHex.push(codhex);
        console.log(listaHex);
    }

    var hexgrupoa1 = document.getElementById("hex-grupo-a-1");
    hexgrupoa1.textContent = listaHex[0]
    
    var hexgrupoa2 = document.getElementById("hex-grupo-a-2");
    hexgrupoa2.textContent = listaHex[1]

    var hexgrupoa3 = document.getElementById("hex-grupo-a-3");
    hexgrupoa3.textContent = listaHex[2]
    
});


function escolheCorNoArray(){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*cores.length);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Gerador de paletas de cores</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="colors.css">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Zen+Kaku+Gothic+Antique&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <main class="principal">
        <div class= "divisas" id="cabecalho">
        <h1 class="titulo">Gerador de paleta de cores</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="parte-central">
            <div id="container-botao">
                <button id="botao-gerar">Gerar</button>
            </div>
            <div id="conteiner-combinacoes">
                <div class="lista-combinacoes">
                    <div class="amostra" id="amostra1"></div>
                    <div class="amostra" id="amostra2"></div>
                    <div class="amostra" id="amostra3"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="lista-hex-anteriores" id="hexlist1">
                    <span class="hex-amostra" id="hex-grupo-a-1">1 &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp </span>
                    <span class="hex-amostra" id="hex-grupo-a-2">2 &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp</span>
                    <span class="hex-amostra" id="hex-grupo-a-3">3 &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div class= "divisas" id="rodape"></div>
    </main>
        <script src="gerador.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining listaHex inside for-loop, this reinitialized it with empty array with each iteration.

```
for (i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
  var listaHex = []; //<--------this is the problem
  var codhex = "";
  var indiceArray = escolheCorNoArray();
  codhex += cores[indiceArray];
  listaHex.push(codhex);
  console.log(listaHex);
}
```

define `var listaHex = [];` outside the loop